# How to record animation in runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some animations for upper body and lower body. I use avatar mask and set weight for them so them can override each other. I have 1 button for each animation. You can see it in this video.

https://youtu.be/fYdoFFJCuxk

All I want is how can I record the animation that I play in runtime and export it to a file(anim, fbx, ...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are playing the animations in runtime already in the video. You want to record a determined clip that can be re-played (with exact movements) from file?

Comment: Yes. I want to record all animation that my model does in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not trivial, meaning that maybe you need to try something out to narrow down the specific problem you might encounter in your attempt.
I am not 100% about how would I do it but I think there are 2 options.

1.- Runtime animation info serialize + save and load:
You would need to have a script that keeps track of the animation's state machine to save that info along the timeline. This script should save the info to a file (.xml, . json or text) so that it can be loaded and played. This info should hold basically the time and the state of the animation changes along the timeline since the animation play.

2.- Transform record:
You can have component for all the gameobjects you want to track that serialize and store the transform of your gameObject along a timeline. This is basically a replay system. If you play the animation, all the transforms info is saved to file (positions and rotations) and then when loaded, this positions and rotations are applied to the respective gameObjects.
You can give a look to the [Easy replay system](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/easy-replay-system-158370) asset in the asset store. I bought it, it really simple and works really good. I tried it also with animations and it works.
Does not have the serialization and save and load part, but you can work that out very probably.

From scratch I think the best option is 1. With some asset, that might be more expensive if includes the serialization and save/load part, maybe you can get it done faster with option 2.